# Write a text file to a sub-folder

Tags: c#, winforms, filepath, streamwriter

I am trying to write out a text file to: `C:\Test folder\output\`, but without putting `C:\` in.

i.e.

This is what I have at the moment, which currently works, but has the `C:\` in the beginning.

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Test folder\output\test.txt");
```

I really want to write the file to the output folder, but with out having to have `C:\` in the front.

I have tried the following, but my program just hangs (doesn't write the file out):

```
(@"\\Test folder\output\test.txt");

(@".\Test folder\output\test.txt");

("//Test folder//output//test.txt");

("./Test folder//output//test.txt");
```

Is there anyway I could do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want this sub-folder to be at the root of the current drive or you are looking for something else? (i.e. create a sub folder in the applications directory).

Comment: Why do you want to remove the C:\?

Comment: @e4rthdog: I already have the sub folder created, I just want the text file written out to this folder now.

Comment: what is the problem with "c:" ? (why would you want to not include this?) - first thing was answered by habib (\\ = networkshare), second one only works if there is Test folder and output in your working directory, 3 and 4 are just *nix-variants of 1 and 2...

Comment: @Robuust: because I need to send my program to other people (within my company), so that they can just use it in the folder I have it in.

Comment: And if you have 3 local hard drives how the app knows where you want to write? I cant understand how you exclude the Drive letter in your logic, sorry

Comment: The app should know where the app is itself

Comment: Thanks, it's still not working. I will have to think about how I am approaching this, and re-approach it again in a different way.

Comment: what do you mean by hangs? there must some exception occured.. if so post the error here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for helping guys.

A colleague of mine chipped in and helped as well, but @Kami helped a lot too.

It is now working when I have:

```
string path = string.Concat(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"\Output\test.txt");
```

As he said: "The `CurrentDirectory` is where the program is run from.

Answer (score 2):

I understand that you would want to write data to a specified folder.  The first method is to specify the folder in code or through configuration.

If you need to write to specific drive or current drive you can do the following

```
string driveLetter = Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.CurrentDirectory);
string path = diveLetter + @"Test folder\output\test.txt";
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path);
```

If the directory needs to be relative to the current application directory, then user `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` to get the current directory and use `../` combination to navigate to the required folder.

Comment: Awesome, that will have to do. it works now - but that is also a similar way of saying "use C:\" - I will have to use the C:\ for now. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A common technique is to make the directory relative to your exe's runtime directory, e.g., a sub-directory, like this:

```
string exeRuntimeDirectory = 
    System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
        System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

string subDirectory = 
    System.IO.Path.Combine(exeRuntimeDirectory, "Output");
if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(subDirectory))
{
    // Output directory does not exist, so create it.
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(subDirectory);
}
```

This means wherever the exe is installed to, it will create an "Output" sub-directory, which it can then write files to.

It also has the advantage of keeping the exe and its output files together in one location, and not scattered all over the place.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName` to get the directory of your running application and then you can add to this the rest of the path..

I don't get clearly what you want from this question , hope this get it..