# Writing a File to the Specified Folder

Tags: c#, streamwriter, visual-studio-express, savefiledialog

This question is in conjunction with my other: [Write a text file to a sub-folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13342263/write-a-text-file-to-a-sub-folder).

This time, I have a program that has a text folder to open a file, then extract data from that file. Then I can save it by saying where to save it.

```
private void btnExtract1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnExtract1.Enabled = false;
    string path = txtSave1.Text;

    string file1;
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(txtFile1.Text)))
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path))
    {
        while ((file1 = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            file1 = file1.Replace("\"", string.Empty);
            file1 = file1.Substring(0, 8);

            line_number1 += 1;

            if (line_number1 >= 1)
            {
                writer.WriteLine(file1);
            }
        }
    }
    btnExtract1.Enabled = true;
}

private void btnSave1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult result = savefile1.ShowDialog();
    txtSave1.Text = savefile1.FileName;
}
```

No it is not saving in that folder. In fact, it breaks at:

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path))
```

With this error:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

What could possibly be wrong?

Comment: Apply a directory check before writing the stream to a file. If the Directory doesn't exist, create the directory.

Comment: Is it possible that you haven't set the value of `txtSave1`? Put a breakpoint there and see what is the value of `path` variable.

Comment: @RePierre, It is set to whatever the user wants it at. i.e. C:\temp\test.txt. If I hover over the path, it shows: "C:\\temp\\test.txt\\"

Comment: @Kevdog777, the "\\" at the end of  the path may be the cause of your problem. How did those got there?

Comment: @RePierre, its what was put there in the code. I didn't add it there.

Comment: @Kevdog777, check how those got there. "\" is illegal character for file name and thus cannot be returned by `savefile1.FileName`. That will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks @RePierre, I will give that a go a bit later and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks @RePierre, I kinda made a rookie mistake - my path was `C:\temp\` and I wasn't saving a file. It is working properly now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a rookie mistake, where I forgot to say what file it is to save as.

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path))
```

Where `path` is equal to whatever the user wants it as - in my case it was set to `C:\temp\`. I haven't set the `SaveFileDialog` to save as any default name.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check how your path looks like? Maybe you're not escaping the `\` properly or you have some invalid characters inside your path.